# oracle trigger to make insert lowercase and replace a character

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a text field in my application that users can input the location of a file. I need to create a trigger that will make that input lowercase and replace a forward slash `/` with a backwards slash `\` if they put a forward slash. The column I want to change is name in the Location table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER lcase_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON LOCATION
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.name = REPLACE(LOWER(NEW.name),chr(92),chr(47));
```

Comment: Hi fdellagr, please provide an example of what you tried and a minimum, complete, verifiable example. See here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Just added what I have tried in my post

Comment: Don't modify incoming data silently. It is just asking for trouble. It would be better to just *constrain* the data and forbid noncomplying input. Then it's up to the *caller* to decide what transformations to apply.

Answer (score 3):

`SET` is part of a SQL update statement, it isn’t part of the PL/SQL language. You also need to prefix pseudorecord references with a colon; and PL/SQL assignment uses `:=` rather than `=`.

```
:NEW.name := REPLACE(LOWER(:NEW.name),chr(92),chr(47));
```

I think you have your ASCII values the wrong way round based on your description; this replaces a backslash with a forward slash. You don’t need to use `chr()`, it might be clear to just use text literals:

```
:NEW.name := REPLACE(LOWER(:NEW.name),'/','\');
```

or the other way round depending on which you really meant.